# How do I know if Microsoft Bluetooth stack is being used instead of a vendor's?

Tags: windows-7, bluetooth

How do I know if Microsoft Bluetooth stack is being used instead of a vendor's?

Answer (score 1):

From my experience with XP and 7 when using third party stacks the options for the notify Bluetooth icon (file transfer and so on) are also from the vendor (like Toshiba). Usually that is easy to spot because they don't have the characteristic look of Windows dialogs.

When there is no third party driver the Bluetooth features are provided by Windows itself (supposing that the device is compatible with the drivers shipped with Windows).